# IntersectClipRect is blocked on Win8.1 & GetDC is blocked on Win10

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mfc, gdi

I have a win32 application runs in IE web browser hosted by an active x control. My application works as a child window of the active x control. When I resize the IE, the whole OS will be frozen. 
By using the remote debugger, I found my application run to IntersectClipRect (on Win8.1) or GetDC (on Win10) when the desktop was frozen. These two API don't return and it seems the DWM is blocked to composite the desktop.
There is no problem when running this on Win 7.
I've not yet found any explanation on MSDN, nether IntersectClipRect nor GetDC shouldn't have been blocked anytime. 
The following is my code for handling WM_PAINT and WM_ERASEBACKGROUND message:

```
BOOL CRunView::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    ::EraseWindow(pDC, this);
    return TRUE;
}
void EraseWindow(CDC* pDC, CWnd * window)
{
    // Set brush to desired background color.
    CBrush
        backBrush(GetWindowLong(window->GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_USERDATA)),
        *pOldBrush = pDC->SelectObject(&backBrush);
    CRect rect;

    SelectPalette(pDC->m_hDC, (HPALETTE)getPalette(), false);
    RealizePalette(pDC->m_hDC);
    pDC->GetClipBox(&rect);
    pDC->PatBlt(rect.left, rect.top, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), PATCOPY);
    pDC->SelectObject(pOldBrush);
}
void CRunView::OnPaint()
{
    RECT r = { -1, -1, -1, -1 };

    INT32 zoomFactor = getZoomFactor();

    if (zoomFactor <= 1)
    {
        GetUpdateRect(&r);
    }
    else {
        GetClientRect(&r);
        r.right = r.right / zoomFactor;
        r.bottom = r.bottom / zoomFactor;
    }

    CPaintDC        dc(this);

    SendRepaintRequest(WindowHandle, r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom);
}
```

The SendRepaintRequest in OnPaint will notify another thread to draw something on client area of main window. So, most of drawing operation is not on UI thread in my application. When drawing on main window, I use GetDC to get the window dc and after drawing, I use ReleaseDC. The application works well when it is not hosted in the active x control.

Comment: Isn't drawing is meant to be done on UI thread? Or you are drawing to a memdc that you bitblit later?

Comment: Did you try not to `EraseWindow` from `CRunView::OnEraseBkgnd`?

Comment: Is `SendRepaintRequest` a blocking call? Does the window class have the `CS_OWNDC` class style? Would that explain the deadlock when two threads are trying to request the **same** DC? Besides, you **really** shouldn't be rendering to a window from a thread other than the owning thread.

Comment: I tried to not handle WM_ERASEBACKGROUND, then it still freeze the desktop and the code run to other GDI function, such as PolyLine().